# Stop function abrupt, remove queue

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, setinterval

So, I have a function that has to animate an icon:

https://jsfiddle.net/1658eaLr/

What I want, is when the mouse leaves the element `.button8`, that the function will stop abruptly and remove the queue.

The problem is, is when I go in and out very fast with the mouse, the animation messes up.

I also tried to use `graph().stop();`, but that didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to the `clearInterval` method you are already using, `setTimeout` will return a unique *timeoutId* which you can use to cancel all the pending timeouts using [window.clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout).

So, keeping most of your code untouched, you could write

```
var interval, timeout;
var graph = function(){
$('.graph-line1').addClass('graph-line1-animate');
timeout = setTimeout(function(e){
    $('.graph-line2').addClass('graph-line2-animate');
    timeout = setTimeout(function(e){
        $('.graph-line3').addClass('graph-line3-animate');
         //... rest of the timeouts
```

And then in the "hover out" callback

```
clearInterval(interval);
clearTimeout(timeout);
```

[Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/La90oqjL/).

As an aside, these nested timeouts could be written a bit more cleanly to avoid the "callback hell". [Here's my quick attempt](https://jsfiddle.net/La90oqjL/5/), but I bet you could do even better.

Comment: Nice, it worked! Thank you so much! I totally forgot to reset the timeouts :p

Answer (score 1):

Building on the above answer, you can also get rid of half the code by deleting the whole `interval =` set of callbacks and changing the bottom as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $('.button8').hover(function(e){
  graph();
  interval = setInterval(graph, 2000);
}, function(e){
  clearInterval(interval);
  clearTimeout(timeout);
});
```